# Fast Food Conversation - Any Practical Guides?

Tags: words, set-phrases, food, phrase-requests

I looked up for fast food conversation but I could not find anything very practical.
While most guide always emphasize on how to order, I never found it prepares one to understand what a fast food clerk may ask.

For someone with basic understanding of the language, I think I can go as far as going to a fast food, greeting and ordering using the name of the item or the number of the set I would like. But most of the time I have to admit I don't understand what subsidiary questions are asked... I always imagined that the cashier may have asked dine-in or take-out or perhaps how I would want to pay but I always ended up stuck here (but eventually always getting the set I wanted) and still a bit frustrated I could not enjoy the "basic" conversation.

Would someone be kind enough to depict a full conversation trying to focus and what may be asked? Or at least how would a cashier ask the following:

> - Do you have any point card?
> - Is this for take-out or dine-out?
> - Would you like a tray?
> - Would you like to up-size your set?

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to JLU!  I think this question may be too open-ended and runs the risk the being closed.  You might refine it by asking something more specific, like how to say "dine-in" vs. "carry-out", etc.  On a side note, I'm not sure that a cashier would ask you how you want to pay, unless credit cards are becoming way more prevalent than they used to be.

Comment: Thanks istrasci. it is just hard to focus on a particular conversation item as I never understood what was being asked. this said I did had what come to mind as specific requests.

Comment: Conversational Japanese. The right word at the right time by Anne Kaneko covers most everyday situations for you to practice. There is not a section for going to McDonalds (so this not a true answer) but the there is a chapter on shopping.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is since it's too broad, and the more specific stuff you asked for is just a simple translation request. You might want to look, for example, somewhere like [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=carryout&ref=wl)

Comment: This question is a bit broad, but I think a few phrases might help you out. The phrases I hear from the staff at fast food places are generally always the same. "店内でお召し上がりですか？" This is generally asked first and means "Will you eat here?" to which you can reply either "Yes" or "持ち帰りで(お願いします)" (take away please). Then you can go ahead and order. Another one I hear often is "ご注文をお伺い致します" which means "I'll take your order now", so all you have to do is say what you want. Hopefully these 3 phrases can help you out.

Comment: I think I often hear "(本日は)こちらでお召し上がりですか?" for "Will you eat here?". I don't think they ever ask you if you'd like a tray but they sometimes ask you if you'd like a drink or french fries with your hamburger, like「ご一緒[いっしょ]に、ポテト(orお飲み物)はいかがですか?(+ただいま半額[はんがく]になっておりますetc.)」 and if you say "no thank you" they say 「では、また次回お願いします」or something like that. The only place that I know has a point card system is Mister Donut (They have "ミスド クラブ ポイント カード"). They might ask you "ミスドクラブカードはお持ちですか?" or something. And.. sometimes they ask you to be seated and wait: "こちらの番号札[ばんごうふだ]を持って、お席のほうでお待ちください"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any point card?
ポイントカードお持ちでしょうか。

Is this for take-out or dine-out?
店内でお召し上がりでしょうか。

Would you like a tray?
(They don't really say this)

Would you like to up-size your set?
(They don't really say this)

**Bonus**

How many payments would you like to split your credit card bill into?
お支払方法は？ or
お支払回数は？

May I remove your plates?
お[済]{す}みのお[皿]{さら}お下げしてもよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: this is great information. I suppose I now have to try it.